# INSERTING form input data to excel sheet from angular2

Tags: excel, angular2-forms

I have a requirement, in which i have to insert data from the angular2 form input fields to excel sheet on SUBMIT button click, i.e. everytime the SUBMIT button is clicked, the data entered into the form should get inserted to the excel sheet.It will be really great if you can help me.